# UWP - Google Analytics - Set Custom dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, uwp, measurement-protocol, google-analytics-sdk

I use [UWP.SDKforGoogleAnalytics.managed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UWP.SDKforGoogleAnalytics.Managed/) and i had wrote these rows

```
Dim _TrakerId As String = "UA-XXXX0-0"

Dim MyTraker As GoogleAnalytics.Tracker = GoogleAnalytics.AnalyticsManager.Current.CreateTracker(_TrakerId) MyTraker.ScreenName = "Images"

Dim Hit = GoogleAnalytics.HitBuilder.CreateScreenView.Build

MyTraker.Send(Hit)
```

All work good... BUT... now i'd like to use Custom dimensions. 
Can anyone help me ??
Where can i set the value ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in C#

```
var myTracker = GoogleAnalytics.AnalyticsManager.Current.CreateTracker("XXXXX");
myTracker.ScreenName = "Images";
var hit = GoogleAnalytics.HitBuilder.CreateScreenView();
hit.SetCustomDimension(1, "Test");           
myTracker.Send(hit.Build());
```

**VB**

My vb is very rusty it might be something like this

```
Dim _TrakerId As String = "UA-XXXX0-0"

Dim MyTraker As GoogleAnalytics.Tracker = GoogleAnalytics.AnalyticsManager.Current.CreateTracker(_TrakerId) MyTraker.ScreenName = "Images"

Dim Hit = GoogleAnalytics.HitBuilder.CreateScreenView
Hit.SetCustomDimension(1, "Test");  
MyTraker.Send(Hit.Build)
```

Comment: I had just tried this solutions but it's  don't work,,,

Comment: Define dosent work. Remember it takes 24-48 hours for data to appear in the standard reports

Comment: I see the 'Images' counter increase but if I analyze the custom dimensions nothing appears. As if he did not receive the data.

Comment: It probably did as I said it takes time for data to appear in the standard reports it's processing only the real time reports are instant. Check tomorrow

Comment: I waited but unfortunatly the custom sizes did not appear.
I had insert data from another device, with another app and appear...so the timeing is not the problem..  :-(

Comment: Check that you have the correct custom dimension number and that it's not a metric

Comment: I have custum dimension.

Answer (score 0):

I have custum dimension.
Before i had used another SDK..but with the old sdk i can't change the tracking ID...  Custom dimension before works good.

GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SetCustomDimension(1, 'Title')    'Title
        GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SetCustomDimension(2, 1234)  'ID

```
    GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendView("Images")
```

Now with new SDK

Dim MyTraker As GoogleAnalytics.Tracker = GoogleAnalytics.AnalyticsManager.Current.CreateTracker(_TrakerId)

```
    MyTraker.ScreenName = "Image"


    Dim Vista = GoogleAnalytics.HitBuilder.CreateScreenView
    Vista.SetCustomDimension(1, 'Title')
    Vista.SetCustomDimension(2, 1234)  'ID

    MyTraker.Send(Vista.Build)
```

in my opinion is correct...but not work :-(